# Null pointer exception request url gmaps v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm doing an app that traces the route between two addresses so with lat lng it works perfectly

```
String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";
```

Now I'm getting the origin and destination of inputs from the user, so far is ok.
I am debugging the code and the url to route calls mounted successfully in my browser. But the error code in Java Null Point Exception occurs exactly in line:

```
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
```

Here is the complete code, do not understand why it gives null pointer exception if the url is valid mounted. Can anyone help me I do not know how to solve

```
public class GMapV2Direction {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public GMapV2Direction() { }

public Document getDocument(String origin, String destination, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + origin  
            + "&destination=" + destination 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

    Log.d("GoogleMapsDirection", url);
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
```

}

Edited: printStackTrace

```
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478): Process: br.com.myapp, PID: 24478
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.myapp.Search}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at br.com.myapp.GMapV2Direction.getDurationValue(GMapV2Direction.java:69)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at br.com.myapp.Search.onCreate(Search.java:59)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-12 15:27:27.459: E/AndroidRuntime(24478):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace?

Comment: Rajesh I edited the question with stack trace.

Comment: You have a RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo.   are you sure the problem is with google?

Comment: I believe so because debugging the code the error occurs on the line where I HttpPost HttpPost = new HttpPost (url); but the url is not empty

Comment: The NPE is in the line 69 of `GMapV2Direction.java`. Post what is in there.

Comment: Posted the complete class GMapV2Direction where the query is done the route and analyzed the xml. Analyzing the line 69 is in the public int getDurationValue (Document doc) method, I think there is something wrong in the analysis of the return on Google.
But still do not understand why when I pass latitude and longitude code works. How can I convert addresses to latitude and longitude before asking the route?

Answer (score 0):

My be UI Thread is waiting for Http execute.
Use Asynctask for HttpClient a try set timeout for HttpClient with command like below.

```
         HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
         client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.version", HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
         client.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 2000);
         client.getParams().setParameter("http.protocol.content-charset", HTTP.UTF_8);
         httpParameters.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
         HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
         request.getParams().setParameter("http.socket.timeout", 5000);
         List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("prm1", prm1value));
         try {
         UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, HTTP.UTF_8);
         request.setEntity(formEntity);
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
         ...
         ..
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution for me was to geocode Addressbook origin and destination from the user input and capture the latitude and longitude to query the route the way it was working.

```
/*
 * Geocodifica os endereços de origem e destino digitados pelo usuário
 */

Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);
List<Address> resultsOrigin = null;
List<Address> resultDestination = null;
try{
    try {
        resultsOrigin = coder.getFromLocationName(origin, 1); 
        resultDestination = coder.getFromLocationName(destination, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }if(resultsOrigin != null){
        Address locationOrigin = resultsOrigin.get(0);
        fromPosition = new LatLng(locationOrigin.getLatitude(), locationOrigin.getLongitude());
        Address locationDestination = resultDestination.get(0);
        toPosition = new LatLng(locationDestination.getLatitude(), locationDestination.getLongitude());
    }
}catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
}
```